# Recursive Insertion Sort with unexpected stack

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion

I am trying to write the InsertionSort in recursive manner and I came up with the following code.

```
function recursiveInsertionSort(array) {
    sort(array, array.length - 1);
}

function sort(array, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        sort(array, index - 1);
        let j = index - 1;
        let key = array[index];
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly.

For example, if input is `[4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7]`, its returning `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16]`.

At line `let key = array[index];`, I am just trying to store the value at current index in a temporary variable and using it inside the loop.

If I don't store it in a variable instead use it directly as shown in the following code, I am getting wrong output i.e., array is not sorted. I didn't understand why it is behaving that way. Even recursion stack seems to be perfect to me. But I am getting a weird output.

```
function sort(array, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        sort(array, index - 1);
        let j = index - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > array[index]) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = array[index];
    }
}
```

For example, if input is `[4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7]`, its returning `[ 4, 4, 4, 4, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 ]`.

Could any one please help me with this? This is actually shattering my understanding of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array[index]` is changed on first step.(when `j` is `index - 1`)

```
j = index -1
array[j+1] = array[j] => array[index]= array[index-1]
```

So if you don't save `array[index]` to `key`, you will lose data when sorting.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I missed that small thing.